# Calculate storage requirements for a data set

Tags: integers, efficiency, storage

I have a simple problem. I can't seem to even find the right search terms to get me pointed in the direction I need to be heading.

I'm writing a bunch of integers to disk. Lot's of them.

Starting with the integer 2, I add it to another integer, write the result to disk, and start the process again using the result as the seed.

This pattern is helping me generate data I need for other research, but I need to apply this pattern until I've reached integers with a length of 10,000 digits or more.

So, here is my simple question: given a set of data of a known data type, how do I calculate the storage space required to store that set?

At the moment, I'm doing this incredibly simple task in Python, recording longs to disk as binary in a single file. But, on my very small machine, I was only able to store the integers my process produced with values between 0 and 42 billion.

Short of my goal of recording a data set with values between 0 and 1e10000.

Given that I have no exposure to formulas for calculating hardware requirements for storing data like this, I have no idea if I'm using the most efficient language and data type for storing as many integers as possible in as little space as possible.

Comment: You could generate the numbers and keep a tally of how much space would be required to store them, without actually storing them.

Comment: You will need to pick a representation for arbitrary-size integers. Can you pick your own? If you can it may be possible to optimize it for their distribution (density as a function of value).  You don't want to use a fixed-length representation.

Comment: If you use Java there is a quick way to store arbitrary precision (arbitrary long) integers efficiently: use BigInteger type and its toByteArray() method to convert them in a byte array having the required length (and easily store them on a file). In order to store a 10000 digits integer you need only 4K (4153 bytes). So in a 1GB of disk space you can store ~240000 10000 digits integers.

Comment: Is your process generating $2,4,6,8,10,\ldots,10^{10000}$, or is it generating $2,4,8,16,\ldots$? In the first case, you won't be able to store everything, since there are $10^{10000}$ number in total, each requiring at least one bit. In the second case, the amount of storage required is roughly double the amount required to store the last one. If the last one is $N$, you need about $\log N/\log 256$ bytes to represent it.

Comment: Yuval brings up a good point: I apply two sieves to the set of all positive integers. The first sieve yields a set with constant density across the entire number line--something like `2,4,6,8,10,...`. The second sieve creates another set with rapidly diminishing density--something akin to `2,4,8,16,...`

Of course, I would like to store both sets so that I can perform analysis on them both with fewer limitations. But, I recognize the need to start optimizing my approach to work within the limitations of today's hardware as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Yuval, where can I get more information about the formula you provided in your comment?

`log N/log256`

Is the 256 derived from the minimum amount of storage space required to write one datum to disk?

Comment: Thanks, Vor! I had been pointed to Python about a year ago when I first asked some colleagues at my previous job which language they would use. (That office has a strong propensity for Python adoption.) At my current job, I have been asked to pick up Java, anyway. So, yeah--two birds with one stone. What could be better?

Comment: @Imizuhashi (1) The formula $\log N/\log 256$ comes from the fact that $k$ bytes can represent $256^k$ different numbers, and a reasonable representation will be almost optimal in  the sense the one of the first $256^k$ numbers will be representable in $k+O(1)$ bytes. (2) You can't store the sequence $2,4,6,8,10^{10000}$ since there are not enough atoms in the world to store so many numbers.

Comment: @Yuval Perhaps I'm missing something here. I used this function to create an integer that has a little over 50,000 digits:<br/ >
>>>> def getFactorial(n):<br/ >
>...    r = 1<br/ >
>...    for x in range(n):<br/ >
>...      r = r * (n + 1)<br/ >
>...    return r<br/ >
>... <br/ >
>>>> getFactorial(100000)<br/ >

Comment: @Yuval Sorry about that. Apparently, you can't use that markup in comments. =) Perhaps I'm missing something here. I used a custom function in Python to create an integer with roughly 50,000 digits. Then I tried `log n / log 256`, substituting my 50,000 digit integer for n--and got `207620.68626643857 bytes`. Double that sounds way too small to store `0...~1e50,0000` to me. That's roughly only 416 kilobytes to store a set of rapidly diminishing density, right?

Comment: @lmizuhashi You're right, I got the formula wrong. If $n$ takes $B$ bytes, then in total you need something like $4B^2$ bytes. Indeed, if $n$ takes $b$ bits, then in total you would need around $b+\cdots+1 \approx b^2/2$ bits, or $b^2/16$ bytes. Since $b=8B$, $b^2/16 = (8B)^2/16 = 4B^2$.

Comment: @Yuval This is cool stuff. Can you recommend any books or papers on where I can learn more about calculating hardware requirements? (After this, I'll need to calculate the RAM / Pagefile size required to multiply two very large inters together and save their result.)

Comment: @lmizuhashi This is basic arithmetic, and doesn't have anything to do with hardware requirements.

Comment: What query operations do you need to perform on the final collection of numbers?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to interpret your dataset generating process. The first produces all even numbers between $2$ and your bound: $2$, $4$, $6$, $8$, …; the second produces all powers of $2$ between $2$ and your bound: $2$, $4$, $8$, $16$, … An integer $N$ requires roughly $\log_{256} N$ bytes to store. Therefore, if your bound is $N$, the first interpretation will take about
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N/2} \log_{256} (2k) \approx \int_1^{N/2} \log_{256} (2x) \, dx \approx (N/2) \log_{256} N \text{ bytes}. $$
The second interpretation, assuming $N=2^m$, will take about
$$ \sum_{k=1}^m \log_{256} 2^k = \sum_{k=1}^m (k/8) \approx m^2/16 = 4(\log_{256} N)^2 \text{ bytes}. $$

Comment: If that were the case, it would be simpler to store the series as a function.